# getting and error using atoi to convert mac address into integer

Tags: c, network-programming

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char buff[] ="AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF";
  char * pch;
  int buffInt[6];

  pch = strtok (buff,":");
  int i = 0;
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    buffInt[i] = atoi(*pch);
    printf ("%c\n",buffInt[i]);
    pch = strtok (NULL, ":");
    i++;

  }
  return 0;
}
```

Im trying to convert the buffer and convert it into int using atoi but it does not seem to work does anyone know any other way to do this.

Comment: `atoi` argument `char *` and 10 base. use `strtol`(ex:`strtol(pch,NULL,16)`)

Comment: and also `%c` --> `%d`

Comment: `%X` or `%#X` would also be appropriate.